# styling div with javascript

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, css

I am trying to style a div which has an asp.net gridview within it.
I am using javascript code.
The div is a popup on asp.net buttonclick event.

I have the code below :

```
function ViewPopup() {

    document.getElementById('PopupDiv').style.visibility = 'visible';
    document.getElementById('PopupDiv').style.display = '';

    var screenHeight = document.documentElement.clientHeight;
    var elementHeight = document.getElementById('PopupDiv').clientHeight;
    if (screenHeight > elementHeight) {
        document.getElementById('PopupDiv').style.top = ((screenHeight - elementHeight) / 2) + 50 +'px';
    }
    else {
        document.getElementById('PopupDiv').style.top = '10px';
        document.getElementById('PopupDiv').style.bottom = '20px';
        document.getElementById('PopupDiv').style.overflow = 'scroll';
    }

    var scrWidth = document.documentElement.clientWidth;
    var elWidth = document.getElementById('PopupDiv').clientWidth;
    document.getElementById('PopupDiv').style.left = ((scrWidth - elWidth) / 2) - 20 + 'px';

    document.getElementById('MaskedDiv').style.display = '';
    document.getElementById('MaskedDiv').style.visibility = 'visible';
}
```

The problem is that .. when the screenheight < elementheight , the control goes to the else statement and a popup
is displayed with scrollbar. Imagine the dimensions of the popup are x and y.

Next time when there is a button click , if  screenheight > elementheight, the control goes to the if statement,
but the popup dimensions are again x and y. That is the dimensions are carried from the earlier button click event.
Is there any way I can make sure that the popup fits the gridview perfectly ?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried putting breakpoints on the var, var and if lines?  Then slowly stepping through the code?  I'd be curious if "slowing" down the JavaScript allows the correct elementheight and screenheight to be obtained.  It's not much of an answer, but I had a similar situation where I had to slow down the code by putting a timer on it so it could get the right dimensions of my element, then continue on to my if statement after the fact.  I'd show the code, but that is with a former employer...

I hope in some way this helps.

Comment: Hey! Thanks for the comments. It did not help in my case. I dont think it is a timing problem. But I dont know what the problem is ..lol.. I appreciate the help !